# How can I extract random elements from an array while not producing any duplicates

Tags: algorithm, arrays

I am using the rand() function in my iPhone project to generate a random array index. I generate several random indexes and then get the objects from those indexes. However I don't want to get one object more than once so is there a way to say generate a random number within the range of the array count (which I am already doing) excluding previously picked numbers.

i.e. something like this:

```
int one = rand() % arrayCount
int two = rand() % arrayCount != one
```

Thanks

Comment: When asking such questions try not to restrict them to certain programming languages. This leads to more answers and makes the question more useful for more people.

Comment: @gs: the implementation of all three of your suggested solutions require knowledge of the particular language's syntax. It makes sense to restrict this question to whatever language the asker is using.

Comment: Yes. But the author of the question is perfectly content with just the abstract explanation I've given him. Therefore he could have just asked for an algorithm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Three possibilities:

### Shuffling

[Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle) your array and extract the elements in their order.

### Remember

Extract a random element and store it into a `NSSet`. If you extract one the next time check if it's already in the set. (This is linear time.)

### Delete

Use a `NSMutableArray` and remove already extracted elements from the array. If you don't want to modify the original one make a mutable copy.

Which one's the best depends on your needs.